# Can I use a red wire as a neutral?

Tags: wiring

I am replacing a 240v wall a/c unit with a 120v one at my workplace. There is no main shut off at the box. Breaker is DP 20A. I would like to move the red wire to the neutral bus with the breaker off to convert this circuit. Along with replacing the outlet. Anyone see problems doing this?

Comment: One problem I see is that you appear to be unlicensed and doing work in a commercial setting. Is money so tight in your workplace that you can't use a professional and get everything that comes with that (insurance, warranty, etc.)?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, where do you see that this is a commercial setting???

Comment: from the OP: "... at my workplace." (Though maybe I'm misunderstanding that an AC unit is simply moving from the workplace.)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wanting the code reference as to why using a red (or black) conductor as a neutral is not allowed:

> ### 2014 National Electric Code
>
> **200.6 Means of Identifying Grounded Conductors.**
>
> **(A) Sizes 6 AWG or Smaller.** An insulated grounded conductor of 6 AWG or smaller shall be identified by one of the following means:
>
> (1) A continuous white outer finish.
>
> (2) A continuous gray outer finish.
>
> (3) Three continuous white or gray stripes along the conductor's entire length on other than green insulation.
>
> (4) Wires that have their outer covering finished to show a white or gray color but have colored tracer threads in the braid identifying the source of manufacture shall be considered as meeting the provisions of this section.

Answer (score 3):

YES! Absolutely this is a problem.

You CANNOT use a red wire for a neutral.

Unless you are in Canada and have a "heating circuit" cable with only a red and black there should definitely be a white wire present.

Comment: This is a dedicated circuit for the a/c. Double breaker was used as 240v before, with a black and red input. White wire runs straight thru receptacle box. This would just be an unused wire (red) if removed from breaker, and going straight to outlet, right?

Comment: Help me understand this, Petey.    We run 12/2 to 240v loads all the time wiring in the black and the white.   We also use the white as a carrier when wiring a light switch.    A little wrap of black tape indicates.    Why is it that we can't wrap a red wire with white tape to indicate it's the neutral?

Comment: Further, I see your point that there aught to be a white wire present and that Rob should use it for this project.

Comment: @Trout, because the codes says so. This is one of those simple "There's no logical reason to question it" types of codes. Code says you cannot use a re-identified red as a neutral, that's all.